# Synonym: [comparison] and [file-comparison]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonym-request

The [comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/comparison) (162 questions) and [file-comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-comparison) (9 questions) tags seem to be synonymous.
The tag wiki for [comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/comparison) specifically mentions file comparisons, so since it has more questions, I propose that all the [file-comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-comparison) questions be retagged to [comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/comparison)

(Personally, I think that file-comparison describes the tag better, but only 9 questions need to be retagged if comparison is used)

Comment: If it is less work, then we should keep `comparison`. However, like you said, I feel that `file-comparison` is better. The former makes me think of a product comparison or something broader than comparing files.

Comment: I find it weird that the former has a `file comparison` tag wiki while the latter has no tag wiki at all. It concerns me that there could be other forms of comparison we might have to consider, I would vote for `comparison` until the other forms of comparison would be clarified. I just don't feel safe with supporting comparison as a synonym of file-comparison.

Comment: They are definitely not synonyms. But as N.N. said, `comparison` is mostly useless and I don't know why the tag wiki even mentions only "file comparison".

Comment: I suggest you remove the checkmark again. We still need moderator support to actually do this, and the "resolved" marker doesn't exactly help there.

Comment: @DanielBeck thanks. I was marking that as I think it is the best solution; I didn't realize that it would be interpreted by the mods as closed

Answer (score 4):

[comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/comparison) seems to be such that it cannot work as the *only* tag on a question and this is [one of the criteria for meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). Therefore, the proper question might not be if it should be a synonym to another tag but *whether it is justified as a tag at all*.

- Looking at some questions tagged with [comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/comparison) they seems to do just as well without the tag. Thus, the tag does not seem to add relevant information which defeats the purpose of any tag.
- There are cases where it does add relevant information but these cases seems to be cases where the questions are more appropriately tagged [file-comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-comparison).

Here is an example to further clarify. If I want to compare technology *x* and *y* (both for which there are tags) it is sufficient to tag the question *x* and *y*. There is no reason to also tag it with [comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/comparison) because *x* and *y* being alternatives already implies a comparison.

Comment: I would disambiguate and nuke the tag. Sometimes, "comparison" is even used for mathematical comparisons.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that `[comparison]` will be recreated within days.

Comment: @DanielBeck In that case it would make sense to also blacklist the tag.

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest to go through the questions and re-tag as needed (e.g. `[file-comparison]`. Once this is done, get a dev to eliminate the tag from the remaining questions.