# Compare [comparison] and [file-comparison]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tags, tag-synonym-request

We have:

[comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/comparison) 201 questions

> File comparison is the process of comparing the contents of files, finding their common contents and their differences, usually using an automated tool

And:

[file-comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-comparison) 26 questions

> Compare files, either line by line, byte by byte or blocks of code.

#### Suggestion

- Merge the two tags.
- The merged tag name should be [file-comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-comparison), but it should have the summary from [comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/comparison).
- [comparison](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/comparison) should be removed.

Please discuss.

Comment: Hi David, can you specify better the reason behind the choice to remove the tag `comparison` instead of `file-comparison`? That tag has 201 questions and 5 followers (30 new question this year) instead of the other one has only 26 question and 1 follower (3 new question this year). It seems people pick out more easily the first one...

Comment: @Hastur I chose that because [file-comparison] is more descriptive of what the tag is about. I don't know the mechanics behind merging but if your suggestion is a lot less manual work then I don't mind going with that. I just think we don't need two such similar tags.

Comment: Given their descriptions, I do think they should be merged like you said, with the final being `file-comparison`, they both describe the same thing and one is too broad, whether or not more users use it.  I do think the 'either line by line...' should be appended to the end of the final description.  Is `comparison` too broad to be a topic here? Like comparing Win 7 vs Win 8?

Comment: surprisingly they're still 3 separate tags as of now. We have another question for them [Synonym: `[comparison]` and `[file-comparison]`](https://meta.superuser.com/q/4482/241386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Let's we make them synonym <sup>[[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/282051)]</sup>.

- **Why not to delete**
  This is a general point of view about the tags change/renaming:
  there is people that distinguishes among similar answers through the tags
  (Similar, not only inside a single stack exchange site).
  Moreover it's possible that I remember how to arrive to a question find in the past specifying that tag and some other words meanwhile I don't remember its title.
  **When we delete a tag we go to damage that kind of memory and research.**
- **Let's do them synonym**<sup>[[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70718/282051)]</sup>
  Said that, I agree that those two tags should be *"synonymized"*.
- **What more**
  We can choose one tag, **leaving the other with an excerpt** that says something similar to:
  "Deprecated tag synonym of the_other_tag, please use the_other_tag instead".